# apache commons: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache, jar, javac

I'm trying to benefite from the `EnumeratedIntegerDistribution()` from `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution`, as shown below.

I'm working wiht jdk7 , on windows Xp, running from Command Line, in one and only project folder

I do:

- download commons-math3-3.2 and unpackage it to my folder, where my java is.
- compile my source with (no errors no warnings)
      javac -cp   commons-math3-3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar  CheckMe.java
- run java CheckMe

### Here is the demonstration:

import java.lang.Math.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedIntegerDistribution;

public class CheckMe {

```
public CheckMe() {

    System.out.println("let us check it out"); 
    System.out.println(generate_rand_distribution (10));
}

private static int[] generate_rand_distribution (int count){
    int[] nums_to_generate          = new int[]    { -1,   1,    0  };
    double[] discrete_probabilities = new double[] { 0.4, 0.4, 0.2  };
    int[] samples = null;

    EnumeratedIntegerDistribution distribution = 
    new EnumeratedIntegerDistribution(nums_to_generate, discrete_probabilities);

    samples = distribution.sample (count);

    return (samples);
}   

public static void main (String args[]) { 
    System.out.println("Main: ");
    CheckMe  animation = new CheckMe();  
}
```

}

However I have got:

ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedIntegerDistribution 
at line 18 - the call for EnumeratedIntegerDistribution()

If I run as I was just advised (below):

```
    java -cp   commons-math3-3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar  CheckMe
```

I get error:    impossible to find the principle class CheckMe

Thanks a lot in advance for your advise.

Comment: You shouldn't translate error messages. Just post them as is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the classpath both when you compile and when you run. So running

```
java CheckMe.java
```

is not enough. Also it should be

```
java CheckMe
```

assuming the class `CheckMe` is not in any package.

You need to execute

```
java -cp commons-math3-3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar CheckMe
```

specifying the jars and other classes your `CheckMe` program needs.

Comment: @Galia Is the `CheckMe` `.class` file in the same directory you're executing the command from?

Comment: You need `.` *and* the jar file on the classpath: `java -cp .;commons-math3-3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar CheckMe`. If you run that from the directory containing `CheckMe.class`, it should be fine.

Comment: It didn't helped. Actually any of my java executables if I run them now (which are not using apache) fail with the error of not finding the principle class. Nether restarting nor using "." as -cp argument didin't change this. Before runnig with clathpass flag my other java exectutables run perfectly.